# Why does dayNamesMin not work in JQuery's calendar?

Tags: jquery, calendar

I'm trying to implement a jquery dateticker but it's not behaving according to the following guide:

https://designmodo.com/calendar-jquery-css3/

This guide says I should be able to set the text that shows for the days of the week with the dayNamesMin field:

```
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
    });
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for me.

I setup the div for the calendar like this:

```
<div class="calendar" id="aug-calendar"></div>
```

And I initialize the calendar like this:

```
    $('#aug-calendar').datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: false,
        dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
    });
```

Just in case you need to see it, here's the calendar class:

```
    .calendar {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

But here's what the calendar looks like:

[image]

The day names still show up as Su, Mo, Tu...

Can anyone explain why dayNamesMin is not working?

---

UPDATE: Here is a link to the live page:

http://hollandandbarnes.azurewebsites.net/entertainment/upcoming-events/

...and the full code for the page:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}

@* the fun starts here *@

<div>
    <div class="logo-and-title-container">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="~/assets/img/logo for upcoming events - 1893x293.png" alt="Holland & Barnes.com" width="500px" />
        </div>
        <div class="upcoming-events-title-container">
            <span class="upcoming-events-title">Upcoming Events Search</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-container">
        <div class="search-textbox-outer-container">
            <div class="search-textbox-inner-container">
                <input type="text" class="search-textbox">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-category-checkbox-group-container">
            <div class="search-category-checkbox-row">
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Annual Festival
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Concerts
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Conventions
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Cultural Events
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Speakers
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Education
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search-category-checkbox-row">
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Sporting Events
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Trade Shows
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Live Theatre
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Fashion
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Business
                </div>
                <div class="search-category-checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Arts
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content-container">
        <div class="calendar-container">
            <div class="calendar" id="aug-calendar"></div>
            <div class="calendar" id="sep-calendar"></div>
            <div class="calendar" id="oct-calendar"></div>
            <div class="calendar" id="nov-calendar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-and-events-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Styles {
    <style>
        .search-category-checkbox-container {
            width: 150px;
        }

        .search-category-checkbox-row {
            width: 90%;
            height: 20px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        .search-category-checkbox-group-container {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            color: black;
            font-family: Futura;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .search-textbox {
            width: 95%;
            border: none;
            height: 46px;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .search-textbox-inner-container {
            border: black solid 2px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 30px 40px;
            height: 50px;
            background: url('/assets/img/search icon.png') no-repeat;
            background-position: right;
            background-origin: content-box;
            padding-right: 5px;
            box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #aaaaaa;
        }

        .search-textbox-outer-container {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .search-container {
            background-color: white;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .upcoming-events-title {
            font-size: 50px;
            color: white;
        }

        .upcoming-events-title-container {
            width: 60%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .logo-container {
            width: 40%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            min-width: 550px;
        }

        .logo-and-title-container {
            background-color: rgb(35,31,32);
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .calendar {
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .ui-datepicker {
            font-family: Futura;
        }

        /*.next, .prev {
            display: none;
        }*/

        /*
        .table-condensed thead tr:first-child .datepicker-switch {
            width: 100% !important;
            margin: auto !important;
            background-color: red;
        }*/

        .main-content-container {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        .calendar-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: rgb(65,64,66);
            width: 300px;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }

        .buttons-and-events-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: rgb(230,231,232);
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        @@font-face {
            font-family: "Futura";
            src: url("assets/fonts/Futura.ttf") format("TrueType"),
        }
    </style>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            for (let month of ['aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov']) {
                $('#' + month + '-calendar').datepicker({
                    showOtherMonths: false,
                    dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
                });
            }

            //$('#aug-calendar thead tr:first-child').addClass('green-background');
            //$('#aug-calendar thead tr:first-child').css('width', '100%');
            //$('#aug-calendar thead tr:first-child').html('<th class="red-background" style="width: 100%;">August</th>');
              
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: what version of jQuery UI datepicker you are using ? Thats calender above does NOT look like jQuery UI datepicker. Please clarify if you want someone to explain why dayNamesMin is not working !!!

Comment: The jquery-ui.css file I have in my project says "jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2016-09-14". Same with jquery-ui.js.

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal example where this problem can be seen - like a js fiddle demo ?

Comment: Yes, I updated the OP with a link to the live page plus the code for that page.